# Deleting duplicate rows when a number is found in different cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wish to remove whole rows where a number matches in a single column, but I want one of the numbers to remain.

I have tried using the delete facility in Google sheets, but it only found 11 duplicates and I know in the test data I am using there are 35

I am sure there is a way to this in Google Sheets if you could explain how to do this that would be great.

Comment: [Google Script App Delete Duplicate Rows with a Specific Value in Specific Column in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53013336/1330560) looks pretty close to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the entire rows are duplicates you can use the function UNIQUE.

Find an empty cell (with room for your data below and to the right), and type

```
=UNIQUE("Your data range here")
```

This will copy your data range excluding duplicates.

If this doesn't help, provide a screenshot of your spreadsheet.